# Prove that the operator $S=T^{*}T+I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products, operator-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector $k$-space with inner product and $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that the operator $S=T^{*}T+I$ is invertible.

I have drafted:

Using the Euclidean Inner Product,
$$\left \langle x,Sx \right \rangle=\left \langle x,x \right \rangle+\left \langle x,T^{*}Tx \right \rangle=\left \langle x,x \right \rangle+\left \langle Tx,Tx \right \rangle=\left \| x \right \|^{2}+\left \| Tx \right \|^{2}\geq \left \| x \right \|^{2}.$$
Therefore, $Sx=0\implies ||x||=0\implies x=0$. That is, $S$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional space and $\ker{S}=\{0\}$. By the Rank Nullity Theorem, $S$ is invertible.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Using the **given** inner product and induced norm..

Comment: What are the possible values for the field $k$?

Comment: It is correct. Your proof works for any inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is correct.

Another way to establish this result is by using eigenvalues:

$T^*T$ being self adjoint $(T^*T)^*=T^*T$ has real eigenvalues $\lambda_k \ge 0$.

Therefore $T^*T+I$ has real eigenvalues $\mu_i:=\lambda_k+1 \ge 1 > 0$,

therefore is invertible (indeed its eigenvalues are $1/\mu_i$, all non-zero).